# Parcel changes file names used in template literals

Tags: javascript, parceljs

I'm developing a memory game with JavaScript. I've decided to create tiles by injection of HTML code by template literals. Problem arises when Parcel modifies file names that have been referenced by function responsible for injecting HTML code.

I'm getting file like this for example:  tile-1.188b0892, instead of tile-1. I've got 20 tile files and I'm connecting tile number to randomly generated image.

How to solve this problem?

```
function createBoard(tilesNum, difficulty) {
  newBoard && newBoard.remove();
  // creatng desired board
  newBoard = document.createElement("div");
  mainBoard.appendChild(newBoard);
  newBoard.classList.add(`board-${difficulty}`);
  // filling board with tiles
  for (let i = 0; i < tilesNum; i++) {
    const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 + 1);
    console.log(randomNum);
    const tile = `
        <div class="tile__container">
            <div class="tile">
            <div class="tile--front" ></div>
            <div class="tile--back" style="background-image: url('/src/assets/tile-${randomNum}.svg')"></div>
            </div>
        </div>`;
    newBoard.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", tile);
  }
}
```

Comment: By importing the asset paths using `import tile1 from './tile-1.svg';`, etc.

Comment: import soud's good. But do I have to import all images at once?

Comment: Format the number: `${randomNum.toFixed(0)}`. But I don't see how Parcel would affect the number produced by `Math.floor`... It might change the name of the variable `randomNum`, but that shouldn't affect how that is rendered.

Comment: You can import them and stuff the names you get into an array and index into it.